# How can I install Bitcoin Core without having a 350GB harddrive?

Tags: bitcoin-core, pruning, installation

I would like to run Bitcoin Core on my laptop with approx 100 Gb of HDD available.

From the installation instructions I understand that a full node must initially download the full approx. 350 Gb blockchain, but can then be pruned down to 5 Gb and still work fine for most use cases such as fully verifying incoming transactions.

Is there a way for me to install Bitcoin Core, and let it download and verify the entire blockchain but continuously pruning it in order to never require more than, say, 50 Gb of data simultaneously?

I cannot find anything about this in the installation instructions at:
https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#initial-block-downloadibd

Thankful for your advice!

/bitcoinomnivore

Comment: If you have enabled pruning correctly it happens during the sync so it doesn't save everything initially and then delete it. Instead it keeps deleting everything above specified limit from old data.

Comment: Thank you, yes this answered my question!